# Can cloudstack be installed on fedora 20?

Tags: installation, fedora-20, cloudstack

Any idea of how I can install Cloudstack(4.4) on Fedora 20?

When trying to install the cloudstack-management rpm of CloudStack 4.4 the RPM requires tomcat-6 and python 2.6, neither of which I can find on the Fedora 20 distribution.

I'm using the cloudstack_installation.pdf for 4.3
I have downloaded the cloudstack RPMs from http://cloudstack.apt-get.eu/rhel/4.4/ (See also: http://cloudstack.apache.org/downloads.html)

I'm running on an x86_64 system.

Any hints are welcome.

Thanks

This is the error I get:

```
     yum install cloudstack-management
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cloudstack-management.x86_64 0:4.4.0-NONOSS_3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: cloudstack-common = 4.4.0 for package: cloudstack-management-4.4.0-NONOSS_3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: cloudstack-awsapi = 4.4.0 for package: cloudstack-management-4.4.0-NONOSS_3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: java7 for package: cloudstack-management-4.4.0-NONOSS_3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: tomcat6 for package: cloudstack-management-4.4.0-NONOSS_3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mkisofs for package: cloudstack-management-4.4.0-NONOSS_3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: MySQL-python for package: cloudstack-management-4.4.0-NONOSS_3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: ipmitool for package: cloudstack-management-4.4.0-NONOSS_3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: ws-commons-util for package: cloudstack-management-4.4.0-NONOSS_3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: python-paramiko for package: cloudstack-management-4.4.0-NONOSS_3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-connector-java for package: cloudstack-management-4.4.0-NONOSS_3.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MySQL-python.x86_64 0:1.2.3-8.fc20 will be installed
---> Package cloudstack-awsapi.x86_64 0:4.4.0-NONOSS_3.el6 will be installed
---> Package cloudstack-common.x86_64 0:4.4.0-NONOSS_3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.6 for package: cloudstack-common-4.4.0-NONOSS_3.el6.x86_64
---> Package cloudstack-management.x86_64 0:4.4.0-NONOSS_3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: java7 for package: cloudstack-management-4.4.0-NONOSS_3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: tomcat6 for package: cloudstack-management-4.4.0-NONOSS_3.el6.x86_64
---> Package genisoimage.x86_64 0:1.1.11-22.fc20 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libusal = 1.1.11-22.fc20 for package: genisoimage-1.1.11-22.fc20.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libusal.so.0()(64bit) for package: genisoimage-1.1.11-22.fc20.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librols.so.0()(64bit) for package: genisoimage-1.1.11-22.fc20.x86_64
---> Package ipmitool.x86_64 0:1.8.13-3.fc20 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: OpenIPMI-modalias for package: ipmitool-1.8.13-3.fc20.x86_64
---> Package mysql-connector-java.noarch 1:5.1.28-1.fc20 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: jta >= 1.0 for package: 1:mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-1.fc20.noarch
---> Package python-paramiko.noarch 0:1.10.1-2.fc20 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python-crypto >= 1.9 for package: python-paramiko-1.10.1-2.fc20.noarch
---> Package ws-commons-util.noarch 0:1.0.1-27.fc20 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package OpenIPMI-modalias.x86_64 0:2.0.19-9.fc20 will be installed
---> Package cloudstack-common.x86_64 0:4.4.0-NONOSS_3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.6 for package: cloudstack-common-4.4.0-NONOSS_3.el6.x86_64
---> Package cloudstack-management.x86_64 0:4.4.0-NONOSS_3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: java7 for package: cloudstack-management-4.4.0-NONOSS_3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: tomcat6 for package: cloudstack-management-4.4.0-NONOSS_3.el6.x86_64
---> Package geronimo-jta.noarch 0:1.1.1-15.fc20 will be installed
---> Package libusal.x86_64 0:1.1.11-22.fc20 will be installed
---> Package python-crypto.x86_64 0:2.6.1-1.fc20 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: cloudstack-management-4.4.0-NONOSS_3.el6.x86_64 (cloudstack)
           Requires: java7
Error: Package: cloudstack-management-4.4.0-NONOSS_3.el6.x86_64 (cloudstack)
           Requires: tomcat6
Error: Package: cloudstack-common-4.4.0-NONOSS_3.el6.x86_64 (cloudstack)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.6
           Installed: python-2.7.5-13.fc20.x86_64 (@f20_x86_64_update)
               python(abi) = 2.7
               python(abi) = 2.7
           Available: python-2.7.5-9.fc20.i686 (distribution-manager-everything)
               python(abi) = 2.7
               python(abi) = 2.7
           Available: python3-3.3.2-8.fc20.i686 (distribution-manager-everything)
               python(abi) = 3.3
           Available: python3-3.3.2-17.fc20.i686 (distribution-manager-updates)
               python(abi) = 3.3
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: You're trying to install packages built for RHEL 6 on Fedora. That's not going to work.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there are any (semi)official Fedora packages? Or is this a question of getting RHEL/Centos or building the RPMs on F18(for tomcat6)?

Comment: You can always try rebuilding the source RPM yourself, e.g. in copr.

Answer (score 0):

The RPM packages are built for centos and are not working with fedora 20 and 21. This is a [known issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CLOUDSTACK-8163), there is also some progress, hopefully in the packages will be available soon.

Answer (score -3):

Install the package "cloudstack-management-4.4.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm "manually. In my case the repo is crashed!
Make download from "http://cloudstack.apt-get.eu/rhel/4.4/"